# Neutral type and retarded DDEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, delay-differential-equations

What are neutral and retarded type delayed-differential equations? Please explain the basic difference between them with examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are really asking too much at the same time.

But briefly, neutral delay equations are a generalization of delay equations in which one can also have derivatives with delays (strictly speaking this is not entirely correct, but this is what can be said without knowing your background, or any answer would be too long). Examples could be
$$
x'(t)=f(t,x(t-1))
$$
for a delay equation, and
$$
x'(t)=f(t,x(t-1),x'(t-1))
$$
for a neutral delay equation.